# Calculate the integral $ \int_{-4}^{4} \max \{ 1+x,1-x,x^2 \} \,dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do you solve a integral problem like this :
$$ \int_{-4}^{4}  \max \{ 1+x,1-x,x^2 \} \,dx  $$

Comment: Find which function is the largest at a given interval. Draw a graph to help you visualize them.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is even, so you're evaluating$$2\int_0^4\max\{1+x,\,x^2\}dx=2\left(\int_0^\varphi(1+x)dx+\int_\varphi^4x^2dx\right)$$with $\varphi:=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. I'll leave the rest to you, using$$\varphi^2=\varphi+1\implies\varphi^3=\varphi^2+\varphi=2\varphi+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since $\max\{1+x,1-x,x^2\}$ is a even function,
\begin{align}
\int_{-4}^4\max\{1+x,1-x,x^2\}dx&=2\int_0^4\max\{1+x,1-x,x^2\}dx\\
&=2\int_0^4\max\{1+x,x^2\}dx.\\
\end{align}
Now, $x^2\ge x+1$ and $x\ge 0\iff x\ge\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$, so

\begin{align}
2\int_0^4\max\{1+x,x^2\}dx&=2\int_0^{\frac12(1+\sqrt5)}\max\{1+x,x^2\}dx+2\int_{\frac12(1+\sqrt5)}^4\max\{1+x,x^2\}dx\\
&=2\int_0^{\frac12(1+\sqrt5)}(1+x)dx+2\int_{\frac12(1+\sqrt5)}^4x^2dx.\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

As said by others, by parity

$$I=2\int_0^4\max\{x+1,x^2\}\,dx.$$

We can pull the term $x^2$ out of the minimum and

$$I=2\int_0^4x^2\,dx+2\int_0^4\max\{x+1-x^2,0\}\,dx.$$

Considering the interval where the first argument of the $\max$ is non-negative,

$$I=2\int_0^4x^2\,dx+2\int_0^\phi(x+1-x^2)\,dx.$$

> $$I=2\frac{64}3+2\left(\frac{\phi^2}2+\phi-\frac{\phi^3}3\right)=43+\frac{5\phi}3.$$